# Obspy: How can I correct for orientation error in horizontal components of borehole seismic data once I have an estimated angle of offset

Tags: python-3.x, orientation, rotational-matrices

When lowering borehole seismometer down a borehole there is little control over the orientation of the horizontal components. Once we have estimated or calculated the angle we need to rotate the reference system to produce traces of seismic data in the North and East directions.

http://docs.obspy.org/packages/autogen/obspy.core.stream.Stream.rotate.html shows ways of changing between ZNE, ZRT, LQT, and LQR. I don't need to do this, and can't do this with data that is not yet in any of those reference systems. I just want to input two traces that represent seismic data in some perpendicular horizontal directions to produce two traces that represent the seismic data in the North and East directions.

Answer (score 3):

sorry for the really later answer. We don't usually monitor StackOverflow. In any case, the current ObsPy master (you will have to update to the dev version if you are still on 0.9.2) has a new function to rotate arbitrarily oriented components to ZNE:

https://github.com/obspy/obspy/blob/a8cf88bfc28b7d06b88427ca626f67418922aa52/obspy/signal/rotate.py#L188-251

Hope it helps!